# Any R-module is free iff R is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Every $R$-module is free $\implies$ $R$ is a division ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/every-r-module-is-free-implies-r-is-a-division-ring)

Prove that if a (generally noncommutattive) ring $R$, any $R$-module is free then $R$ is a field.

The commutative case is fairly easy, but I don't know how to deal with the noncommutative one. What could be the tools, or in what context is this problem solved most clearly?

Although I am somehow a novice in noncommutative ring theory, the problem looks very interesting and I am willing to study something new even for this problem only.

Thank you.

Comment: Dear Adrian: please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75866/every-r-module-is-free-implies-r-is-a-division-ring.

Comment: Great! Thank you! It is even better that I expected, since it fits my knowledge of Wedderburn-Artin theory. Sorry if my question seems a repost...

Comment: Dear Adrian: You're welcome! No apology is needed. By the way, I upvoted your outstanding question.

Comment: Thank you, sir! But why is it outstanding, if I may ask? :)

Comment: Dear Adrian: I had nothing deep in mind. I just told myself this. The question was asked before on MathOveflow - see [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/515/rings-over-which-every-module-is-free) - where it got 16 votes. If you look at the first answers given either on MSE or on MO, you see that they were very complicated, and suddenly a simple argument emerged. I find interesting the fact that there are problems which have a simple solution, but, for some reason, it takes a lot of time to find this solution...

Comment: ... I see that as a kind of [Egg of Columbus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_of_Columbus) phenomenon.